# Could not evaluate formula for value passed to Flow

Tags: apex, process-builder

Has anyone come across this error when trying to use Process Builder/@InvocableMethod to call an Apex class?

This is the error I see in the Debug log:

```
Could not evaluate formula for value passed to Flow Generate_Royalty_Invoice. FlowDefId: 300w0000000CnEL FlowVersionId: 301w00000000IGr: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

This is the error I receive in data loader:

```
Error message:The record couldn't be saved because it failed to trigger a flow.
```

This only occurs when:

- Data is loaded via data loader
- There is more than one record loaded

i.e., it does not happen for records inserted manually or via Apex.

There are no errors in the `@InvocableMethod`

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's as much of the InvocableMethod that you need to see, it successfully `process`es one `ItemToProcess` and then fails seemingly after that - it would eventually go on to pass the id's gathered to a batch job, but it never gets that far (unless you're only processing one record). If I run each record separately, it works every time:

```
global class RoyaltyProcessingService 
{
    @InvocableMethod(label='Process Royalty' description='Processes Royalty Invoice')
    global static void process(List<RoyaltyProcessingService.ItemToProcess> itemsToProcess) 
    {
        Set<Id> invoiceTypeIdsToProcess = new Set<Id>();
        Map<Id,Set<Id>> accountIdsToProcess = new Map<Id,Set<Id>>();

        for(RoyaltyProcessingService.ItemToProcess itemToProcess : itemsToProcess)
        {
            process(itemToProcess.Input, invoiceTypeIdsToProcess, accountIdsToProcess, itemToProcess.InvoicesArePosted);
        }    
    }
}
```

The Process itself is really simple, showing the action for convenience:

[image]

In essence, I am only using the Process as a form of Trigger, so I can switch on/off easily and also pass in a config Boolean - its so much more convenient than  a Trigger, so it would be great to get it working.

Comment: Picklist values are not evaluated correctly in formulas when sObjects are passed in through flow triggers .Are you evalulating picklist in formula ?

Comment: No, there a no picklists on the object...

Comment: There are a few bulkificaiton gothca's around with Process Builder, sadly more than i feel there should have been for v1 GA release. Can you share a screenshot of your setup and some sample code?

Answer (score -1):

I came across same error.
But I set the return type to the same type of input parameter, it worked.
I thought the return type of the InvocableMethod must not be "void" when it processes some records.
Please try it!